# splitting of decimal in vs.net programming

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

i have a project to do so in that i need to do some math calculation

for example if user enters a number `6765333`

and now i have to analyse that the given number should be divided by 180

i will get `37585.183333333`

and now starts the main problem

i want to separate `37585` and `.183333333`

and then multiply only `.183333333` with 6

so i should get `1.1`

this all should be done automatically after the new dynamic number is given

this is in windows application

hope anyone can help me out??

Comment: How nice it would be if people TESTED first, and not supply you with a wrong answer, don't you agree?

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
 decimal no = 6765333m / 180;
 Console.WriteLine(no);
 Console.WriteLine(decimal.Remainder(no, 1) * 6);
```

VB Syntax:

```
 Dim no = 6765333 / 180
 Dim no1=Decimal.Remainder(no, 1) * 6
 Dim no2=Decimal.Round(no1, 1)
```

Comment: @Martin - I've posted my suggestion so OP can try out and secondly the output is correct - OP have to rounding the value.

Comment: If someone asks for an answer, give it, don't beat about the bush

Answer (score 0):

final solution

```
    Dim i As Double = 6765333
    Dim j As Double = i / 180
    Dim k As Double = j - Math.Floor(j)
    Dim sk As String = CStr(k).Substring(0, 11) ' truncate after 9 decimal digits
    k = CDbl(sk)
    Dim l As Double = Math.Round((k * 6) * 10) / 10 ' round on 1 decimal
```

Comment: Solution is correct, but converting to string to truncate is really not necessary. AVD's code is better.

Comment: AVD wrote (editted) his solution, after seeing mine, and reading my comments. That way even a monkey can answer questions.

Comment: I know you got it "right" first, but all I'm saying is that his code is better, that's all. It's not a race, nor a competition, he has the best solution now even though he got it slightly wrong at first (forgot rounding to match expected answer).

Answer (score -2):

You can Try this..
 `decimal val=6765333; 

   decimal divNum=180; 

   decima ans= val/divNum; 

  int intVal = ans; 

  int decVal = ans-intVal;
  //Now You Get decVal = .183333333. So you can calculate it.`

Comment: decVal has value 0, How can an integer have a result with decimal digits???????????